# Deploy a Rails app on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, dreamhost

I am trying to deploy my first Rails app. I copied all files to ~/mysite.com and set up MySql.

[Here's my configuration at Dreamhost](http://img19.imageshack.us/i/immagine5vza.png/).

Now when I visit mysite.com I get a 404 error (which isn't my custom 404 error). It seems that Passenger does not run!

What should I do? Do I need to start Passenger? (touch tmp/restart.txt does nothing)

Comment: Does the apache access or error log say anything? If so please post it here.

Comment: Logs say nothing :( The only informations avaible are here: http://www.foto-fiori.com

Comment: Are you on a VPS?  Dreamhost currently has Rails 2.2.2 installed.  Your backtrace is showing an attempt at using Rails 2.3.3.

Comment: DH has just updated Rails to version 2.3.3: $ rails -v => Rails 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your stack trace at http://www.foto-fiori.com/ it looks like there's a gem missing on your production server. Check the gem list in your environment.rb config file and ensure all gems are installed. You can also ssh into your application and run `rake gems`.

```
rake gems RAILS_ENV=production
```

You may want to freeze the gems if Dreamhost does not allow you to install them.

```
rake rails:freeze:gems
```

Comment: $ rake gems
(in /mnt/local/home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com)
 - [I] mysql 
 - [I] mini_exiftool 

I = Installed

Comment: Can you run "script/console production" in your rails app on dreamhost?

Comment: $ script/console production
Loading production environment (Rails 2.3.3)
>> User.count
=> 7

Comment: Interesting, and that is done when you ssh into your dreamhost server? I'm not too familiar with how Dreamhost is setup, but is it possible that there are multiple versions of Ruby installed? Perhaps Passenger is using a different one than your account is. A different version will likely have a different set of rubygems installed.

Comment: Also take a look at the wiki page: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger. Try specifying the gem path as they show there. It's the 4th point down in the Technical Notes section.

Comment: Thanks @ryanb! script/console runs with my user configuration, while Passenger runs as another user on DH (and so it didn't read my user config). I changed ENV variable in environment.rb and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

4 things to check first:

1. You enabled  Ruby on Rails Passenger (mod_rails) for the domain name
2. You point your domain name configuration to the public directory of your application.
3. Your Rails Version (As of 8/5/2009 Rails is up to 2.3.3 but Dreamhost is at 2.2.2)
4. All your gem dependencies are available at Dreamhost, in your home folder, or are unpacked in your rails application.

If passenger is giving you an error message then your rails app isn't starting, but passenger will put something in the apache logs.

These are in: ~/logs/domain.name/http/

Usually this is because of the wrong rails version or a missing gem or some other mismatch between the dreamhost environment and your development machine.

Comment: Now you can see the configuration following the link above.

Comment: I am having trouble viewing that, I will try again later.

Comment: Now I get an error from Passenger: http://www.foto-fiori.com/
But I can't understand what the problem is: the log says nothing :(

Comment: I just edited the post with some info about what to check if you see the passenger error screen.